# recursive function that calls on itself not doing anything after calling itself

Tags: php

I have a recursive function that calls itself and nothing happens on any of the other calls.
Meaning, the first time the function is ran though it runs fine, but then when it runs recursively none of those calls do anything.

The code looks like this:

```
<?php
for($i=0; i<=$arr.length()-1; $i++;){
    function recursiveEcho(string){
        echo $arr[i];
        recursiveEcho($arr[i+1]);
    }
}
?>
```

The real code will be more complicates than an echo and it works fine outside of this function, but when I put it in It doesn't work.

Comment: Recursion and loop, why? What's this for?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve here. Could you please add an example input and intended output?

Comment: Plus you have syntax errors...

Comment: There is a syntax errors. Lot of. And your `recursion` has no condition to stop. It`s just endless... Plus, you declaring a `function`, but not calling it. Even your loop header is incorrect.

Comment: Assuming the syntax is correct, you will get an error in the second iteration because `recursiveEcho` was already defined in the first iteration.

Comment: __I have a recursive function that calls itself__
That is just pure golden-"meta" right there!  I love that phrase.

Comment: how your recursion stop? I think your recursiveEcho() will call itself until unknown numbers of call?

Answer (score 3):

You code is a little weird. If you want to print all element of the array, you just have to make a simple loop like:

```
for($i = 0 ; i < count($arr) ; $i++) {
    echo $arr[$i];
}
```

But, if you want to make it recursively, you should write something like:

```
<?php

// take the array as reference (avoid copies)
function recursiveEcho(&$arr, $i){

    // Stop the recursion when we are at the end of the array
    if ($i >= count($arr))
        return;

    // print the current value
    echo $arr[$i];

    // recursively call the function for the next value
    recursiveEcho($arr, $i+1);
}


recursiveEcho($arr, 0);

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The real recursive function is addDoucmwnt, which adds a string to an array. addDocument is a private member function so I pass it the instance of the class to access the a

Comment: private add document() inside the function. What is also passed is an array of strings to add. But before recursively adding the remaining strings , it checks if the string is already present in the array. If it is not, then it recursively calls itself. Arguments being instance of class, string to add, and array of already added values. How would you do this?

Comment: I did answer to your initial question. If its a little more complicated, just post a new one, we will take a look. do not add new needs on comment, that will help no one.

Comment: add the link to the new question in a comment here, and be as clear as possible :)

Answer (score 0):

The function you have called is infinitely recursive. While using recursion, you must always use the end condition. To print all elements of the array, use

```
<?php
$arr=[1,2,3,4];
$n=count(($arr);
recursiveEcho(0);
function recursiveEcho($a)
{
    if($a==$n)
        return;
    else
    {
        echo $arr[$a]
        recursiveEcho($a+1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
$arr = [1,2,3,4];

function recursiveEcho($i=0) {
  echo $arr[$i];
  if ($i < count($arr)-1) recursiveEcho(++$i);
}

recursiveEcho(); //=> 1..2..3..4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't define a function more than once; it will blow up your script in the second iteration.

The correct way to implement recursion in this case would be to drop the loop altogether and make a bounded recursive function like this:

```
function recursiveEcho($arr, $i, $n)
{
    if ($i < $n) {
        echo $arr[$i];
        recursiveEcho($arr, $i + 1, $n);
    }
}

recursiveEcho($arr, 0, count($arr));
```